# virtualenv on different Python version throws ImportError

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv

I searched around and haven't seen this posted elsewhere.

My Windows machine uses Python 2.7 as the default Python. I ran `virtualenv` to create a virtual environment that uses Python 3.4:

```
C:\virtualenvs>virtualenv -p C:\Python34\python.exe mypy3
```

and got an error:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:\Python34\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 8, in <module>
    import base64
  File "C:\Python34\lib\base64.py", line 9, in <module>
    import re
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 324, in <module>
    import copyreg
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\copyreg\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from future.utils import PY3
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\utils\__init__.py", line 75, in <mo
dule>
    import functools
  File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py", line 21, in <module>
    from collections import namedtuple
  File "C:\Python34\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from reprlib import recursive_repr as _recursive_repr
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reprlib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Cannot import module from python-future source folder')
ImportError: Cannot import module from python-future source folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to specify the full path of virtualenv:

```
C:\virtualenvs>C:\python34\Scripts\virtualenv.exe -p C:\Python34\python.exe
```

because I was effectively calling this:

```
C:\virtualenvs>C:\python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe -p C:\Python34\python.exe
```

since `C:\python27\Scripts` is in my `PATH`. And the collision of Python 2.7 and 3.4 was causing the issue.